# How to pass SQL query to psql as a argument containing double quotes

Tags: macos, bash, postgresql, psql

I am trying to:

```
psql -c "COPY ( SELECT * FROM "Users" LIMIT 10 ) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER" > out.csv
```

However double quotes inside query (`"Users"`) are removed and psql returns error that `Relation users does not exist`. I tried to escape quotes like this `\"Users\"`. but they are still removed. What can I do?

Comment: Another good reason to avoid identifiers that need quoting...

Comment: So you say that all table names and column names should be lowercased?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

And here is the right answer (it works for me):

```
echo 'COPY ( SELECT * FROM "Users" LIMIT 10 ) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER' | psql > out.csv
```

And even better (it allows to use single and double quotes without any escaping):

```
psql > out.csv <<EOT
COPY
(SELECT id, email, "displayName", "firstName", "lastName", "displayName", 'some str' AS "someStr" FROM "Users" LIMIT 10)
TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER;
EOT
```

Answer (score 6):

```
psql -c 'COPY ( SELECT * FROM "Users" LIMIT 10 ) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER' > out.csv
```

In bash, you can use single quotes in strings provided you don't need to interpolate anything. Of course if your query contained single quotes, that wouldn't work but in your case you should be fine

Comment: And what I can do in case when I have to use both double and single quotes in my SQL query?

Comment: I tried what you wrote but it still removes double quotes from query - maybe this is done by psql for some reason?